# Arbitrary Marker in Rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, rviz-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to put a marker at an arbitrary pose in RViz? What I want to be able to do is put a marker at some xyz in some coordinate frame WITHOUT having to write code. I know I could put a marker there with code

My current method is to create a Grid, which allows you to specify a base frame and offset, but that's hardly efficient.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12951/arbitrary-marker-in-rviz/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can certainly place a marker wherever you like. But, something has to publish it with its position.

What is the requirement for not writing code?

EDIT: To check `tf` calculations without writing additional code, you can use the TF display in `rviz`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2012-02-08**:
Perhaps a simple node that reads a frame_id and point from the keyboard, and publishes a marker there?  Admittedly, it's a bit crufty, but it should accomplish what you want to do.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-02-08**:
I just want to be able to check within RViz. Let's say I have a node that does a TF calculation for me, and it prints out the numbers for where a certain point is. I could change the dependencies of my package to publish a marker, OR I could just throw the point in RViz and see if it matches up.